# Undefined control sequence when adding math comment to \WHILE

Tags: algorithms

I'm pretty new to (La)TeX so please forgive me if this question is stupid :)

I have an algorithm that is typeset with the `algorithm` and `algorithmic` packages.

Then I have this in the algorithm:

```
\WHILE[growingPhase returns $topK \eq \emptyset$ \OR $\sum_{u_i^-} > k^{th}score$]
{$\exists S_i$ such that $S_i \neq \emptyset$ \AND $growingPhase()$}
```

Which gives me an undefined control sequence error. The same line without the comment works fine:

```
\WHILE{$\exists S_i$ such that $S_i \neq \emptyset$ \AND $growingPhase()$}
```

Also another while works fine with comments:

```
\WHILE[latice.maxUpperBound is the largest upper bound among the objects in the latice when fullUpdate() or lightUpdate() was last called]
{$\exists S_i$ such that $S_i \neq \emptyset$ \AND $latice.maxUpperBound > k^{th}score$}
```

So I'm pretty sure it's not the comment, rather the math or the `\OR` in the comment that makes the trouble...

A minimum (non)working example is:

```
\documentclass[twoside,11pt,openright]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage{a4}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[labeled]{multibib}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicforall}{\textbf{for each}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{\hfill// \textit{#1}}

\algsetup{linenosize=\tiny}
\captionsetup[algorithm]{font={scriptsize}}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\WHILE[growingPhase returns $topK \eq \emptyset$ \OR $\sum_{u_i^-} > k^{th}score$]{$\exists S_i$ such that $S_i \neq \emptyset$ \AND $growingPhase()$}
\ENDWHILE
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

(also the comment gives the same error when used in a `\COMMENT{}` macro.)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your MWE is missing a `\STATE` command.  Otherwise the only error is that `\eq` is not defined.  You should just write `=`.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\renewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{\hfill// \textit{#1}}

\algsetup{linenosize=\tiny}
\captionsetup[algorithm]{font={scriptsize}}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\WHILE[growingPhase returns $\mathit{topK} = \emptyset$ \OR $\sum_{u_i^-} >
      k^{th}\mathit{score}$]
{$\exists S_i$ such that $S_i \neq \emptyset$ \AND $\mathit{growingPhase()}$}
\STATE something
\ENDWHILE
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Included is @egreg's suggestion to add the `\mathit` for the multi-letter identifies.  As he also says, consider using `k\text{-th}` (or `k\mbox{-th}` without `amsmath`) instead of superscript.

Comment: I'll remove my answer; would you add my comments to yours?

Comment: doh of course! The = instead of \eg solved it :) Also I simply forgot the \STATE in the example, in reality quite a lot of statements follow inside the \WHILE

Comment: @egreg OK, I've done that.

Comment: I think my multiletter identifiers actually work without \mathit - what is the difference? Also what is the difference between using amsmath (^{th}) instead of \text{-th} or \mbox{-th}?

Comment: @Casper Try to use the function name `Difference()` and after that try `\mathit{Difference}()`. You'll see a big difference. `;-)`